# Linear regression: interpreting main effect in the presence of an interaction with a continuous variable

Tags: regression, interaction, main-effects

I have a classical multiple regression model:
$y=b_0+b_1x_1+b_2x_2+b_3x_1x_2$

where $x_1$ is binary and $x_2$ is continuous and mean-centered. My question is about the interpretation of the estimate $b_1$.

As far as I understand from multiple sources, the interpretation of $b_1$ in the presence of an interaction is as a *conditional effect* for $x_2=0$. That is, $b_1$ corresponds to the effect of a one-unit change of $x_1$ on $y$ when $x_2$ is absent, i.e. $0$.

In my case with a continuous $x_2$ though there is not a single sample in which $x_2=0$. Nevertheless, I have a highly plausible main effect for $x_1$. However, it seems it doesn't make sense to say that $b_1$ corresponds to the effect of a one-unit change of $x_1$ on $y$ when $x_2=0$, since $x_2$ is never zero.

How can I interpret $b_1$ in this case? And does the fact that "$b_1$ *can only be interpreted conditional on* $x_2=0$" mean that $b_1$ is effectively only estimated on samples in which $x_2$ is zero? (Which in this case would be zero samples, i.e. clearly non-sensical).
I'm confused.

**Edit:**
I thought that mean-centering $x_2$ only ensures that the interpretation of $b_1$ is conditional on $x_2$ being at its average value, which may be more meaningful than conditioning on the original zero point of $x_2$. However, [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/477937/on-the-difference-between-the-main-effect-in-a-one-factor-and-a-two-factor-regre) seems to suggest that mean-centering $x_2$ actually achieves that $b_1$ is the average effect of $x_1$ *over all possible values* of $x_2$. This may be relevant for my question.

Comment: Since "all possible values of $x_2$" consist of the entire real line, that average effect interpretation is untenable.  As in all linear regression models, the coefficients are slopes and are interpreted as derivatives.  That *always* works, regardless of the values of the explanatory variables.

Comment: I see. I think this clarified, indirectly, my central misunderstanding. While $b_1$ can only be _interpreted_ as a main effect when $x_2=0$, this does not entail that the estimation of $b_1$ is only based on samples in which $x_2=0$. Also, in the case where $x_2$ is continuous and there are no or only few samples where $x_2$ is exactly zero, the interpretation of $b_1$ as a main effect doesn't make much sense at all. Instead, as the derivative states, the change of $y$ in $x_1$ is generally a function of $x_2$: $dy/dx_1=b_1+b_3 x_2$.

Comment: That's very well put.

Comment: Your statement "mean-centering $x_2$ only ensures that the interpretation of $b_1$ is conditional on $x_2$ being at its average value" is correct. As a corollary, if you change the centering of $x_2$ you would change the "main effect" of $x_1$ should you choose to interpret $b_1$ as the "main effect." This is why I try to avoid use of  "main effect" when there's an interaction: what does a "main effect" of a predictor mean when recoding a different predictor changes its value?